# Is it possible to download things to the Aquarius E4.5?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, downloads, phone

The new ubuntu phone is amazing just missing apps like snapchat, whatsapp, kindle... So is there anyway to download these apps and/ or iTunes or Google play store to the BQ Aquarius E4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it is not possible! If there is an web version you could use that.

But you could contact the company for ubuntu-touch support ;)

> Which applications do run on Ubuntu Touch?
>
> Ubuntu Touch is primarily designed to support web apps, and native
>   apps programmed in qml and javascript or C++. As it is a real Linux,
>   of course all non graphical applications run equally as on any other
>   Linux system. You can ssh to Ubuntu Touch and run any console based
>   application.
>
> X11 is not supported (so far) so all GUI standard applications will
>   not run.

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ)